# vbs syntax error: 800A03EE ')' expected

Tags: visual-studio, vba, vbscript

I try to execute this in a file called 'addcurrentkey.vbs'
But it says ')' is expected in row 1. Character 38.

I tried this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16569/Autorun-Applications

Why can't I execute a .vbs file?

```
Private Sub AddCurrentKey(ByVal name As String, ByVal path As String)
Dim key As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True) 
key.SetValue(name, path) 
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not all of your code, and you don't get the error trying to "save this in a file". Please [edit] your question to provide the code before this procedure declaration, and to provide more details. There are no errors in line 1 of the code you posted.

Comment: @KenWhite it says line one, which is "Private Sub AddCurrentKey(ByVal name As String, ByVal path As String)". Compile error Microsoft VBscript

Comment: You said that already, and I'm telling you the error isn't there. Again, there is no error in line 1 of the code you posted. Please [edit] to provide more information, as I asked in my previous comment. Without it, you're probably not going to get help here, because you're not providing the details we can use to help you.

Comment: @KenWhite So, Can you execute this without error?

Comment: @KenWhite The error *is* there. VBScript doesn't support typed parameters.

Comment: @user10056 Do you want to use VBScript, VBA, or VB.net? They're different languages despite sharing some similarities. The code in the tutorial you referenced is VB.net.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is probably written in VB.net (or perhaps VBA). You are tying to run the code as VBScript, which does not support typed parameters and variables. It also doesn't provide the registry object you're trying to use. Change the procedure from this:

```
Private Sub AddCurrentKey(ByVal name As String, ByVal path As String)
  Dim key As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True) 
  key.SetValue(name, path) 
End Sub
```

to this:

```
Private Sub AddCurrentKey(ByVal name, ByVal path)
  Dim key : key = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite key & "\" & name, path
End Sub
```

and the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

VBScript still uses the "old" Visual Basic syntax.  Which distinguishes between function calls used in expressions and procedure calls that are statements.  You use (parentheses) in an expression but not in a statement.  Fix:

```
 key.SetValue name, path
```

Or if you prefer:

```
 Call key.SetValue(name, path)
```

---

The error message is hard to interpret because the script interpreter thinks that you are trying to write this:

```
 key.SetValue (name), path
```

Which means something completely different.  VBScript passes arguments ByRef.  The extra parentheses around *name* turns it into an expression that creates a copy of the variable.  It can be modified by the SetValue procedure without it affecting the *name* variable.  Not what it actually does nor what you intended.

Comment: That is another issue with his code (one he may want to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) about), but not what's causing the error he described.